# How to use ubuntu packages in pex file

Tags: python, ubuntu

we can not install Tkinter package using pip and want to use Tkinter in pex. Please tell me the way so I can use ubuntu package in pex. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The not-so-easy, but 100% working way:

1. Compile Tkinter with statically linking
2. Create Pypi package, which contains your compiled Tkinter binaries and libraries as a regular files
3. Install this package to your development environment, and use this statically-linked libs and files in your app.
4. pex should work perfectly with this setup!